# Routes changes URL but doesn't display corresponding page

Tags: angular, routes

Am trying to navigate between pages but it doesn't work. I have defined the routes, am using routerLink as per the Angular documentation and have checked countless Stackoverflow subjects but still can't make it work.

My project is new, so I basically only have those 3 components:
_ AppComponent (parent to other 2)
_ WelcomePageComponent
_ LandingPageComponent

This is the app.module.ts where I have defined the routes.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WelcomePageComponent } from './welcome-page/welcome-page.component';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page/landing-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent},
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomePageComponent },
  { path: 'landing', component: LandingPageComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  entryComponents: [
    WelcomePageComponent,
    LandingPageComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomePageComponent,
    LandingPageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the html where I try to create a link to the Welcome page.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a [routerLink]="['/welcome']" routerLinkActive="active">Welcome Page</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

When clicking on the link, the URL does change but not the page. Althought the  displays the Welcome Page content, I'd rather change page completely.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Does it actually display the WelcomeComponent in the `<router-outlet>`? Because that's what it's supposed to do…

Comment: Yes the <router-outlet> displays the WelcomeComponent properly. I added it to test it. However I do not switch page to end up on the Welcome one with the routerLink.

Comment: The Angular router is used to set up Single Page Applications. The whole idea is that there are no page reloads in the browser. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just wanted to navigate between the 3 components I have so far, and believed that it meant changing page when navigating from one to another, by modifying the url using the routerLink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to change your design a bit to achieve what you want.

**Step 1** : Create a `NavComponent`, which will contain all the navigation links. Remove links from `AppComponent`. It should only contain `router-outlet` tag.

**Step 2** : Update route config as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: NavBarComponent},
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomePageComponent },
  { path: 'landing', component: LandingPageComponent }
];
```

Added a [demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/route-nav-comp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnav-bar%2Fnav-bar.component.html)

Comment: Keeping all the links in the NavComponent is part of the best practises to follow? If yes thanks for the tip. However after checking your demo code, I have trouble understanding why your routerLinks work, since their syntax seem similar to the one I tried using.

Comment: Yes, and that's what I mentioned in each step. Refactoring the code.